# How to create Sources from a Seq[Path] in mill build.sc file?

Tags: scala, build-tools, mill

Mill [documentation](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Tasks.html) says

> Sources are defined using T.sources {…​}, taking one-or-more os.Paths
> as arguments. A Source is a subclass of Target[Seq[PathRef]]

So this is possible in mill v0.9.9

```
def sourceRoots: Sources = T.sources { os.pwd / "src" }
```

and this

```
def sourceRoots: Sources = T.sources ( os.pwd / "src", os.pwd / "foobar" )
```

but these do not compile:

```
def sourceRoots = T.sources { os.pwd / "src", os.pwd / "foobar" }
def sourceRoots = T.sources { Seq(os.pwd / "src", os.pwd / "foobar") }
def sourceRoots = T.sources { Seq(os.pwd / "src", os.pwd / "foobar") : _* }
def sourceRoots = T.sources ( Seq(os.pwd / "src", os.pwd / "foobar") )
def sourceRoots = T.sources ( Seq(os.pwd / "src", os.pwd / "foobar") : _* )
```

Is it somehow possible to create `def sourceRoots: Sources = T.sources ...` from a seq of paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two overloads for `T.sources` construction. One accepts `os.Path`s, the other one accepts a `Seq[mill.api.PathRef]`.

To create a `T.sources` from a `Seq[os.Path]`, do the following:

```scala
val paths = Seq(millSourcePath / "src", millSourcePath / "src-jvm")

def sourceRoots = T.sources { paths.map(p => PathRef(p)) }
```

Comment: Thank you! So  it's the overload def sources(values: Result[Seq[PathRef]]). Is there an implicit conversion from Seq[PathRef] to Result[Seq[PathRef]] or how is that achieved?

Comment: Yes, in companion `object Result` there is an `implicit def create[T](t: => T): Result[T]` conversion.